# VBA looping through and writing ADODB Recordset

Tags: vba, excel, recordset

I'm new to working with recordsets, and I'm working on something where I retrieve a recordset from a sql server and then I need to loop through it pasting the values in an excel spreadsheet.

The order of the fields in the recordset is already correct, so I should be able to just move from cell to cell pasting each value within a range, but I'm not sure exactly how to do it. I know the recordset is correct because I outputed it to a file and everything looked in order.

This is my code so far:

```
Public Sub retrieve()

Dim rsTest As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsTest = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rsTest = DataManager.GetData()

Sheets("Planners").Activate
Dim cel As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim rsFields As Variant

Do While Not rsTest.EOF

   For Each cel In ActiveSheet.Range("A3:H1000").Cells
     For Each rsFields In rsTest.Fields

     cel = rsTest(rsFields.Name)

     Next
  Next

Loop

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want all the recordset fields then you can just do this:

```
Public Sub retrieve()
Dim rsTest As ADODB.Recordset

    Set rsTest = DataManager.GetData()

    If Not rsTest.EOF Then
        Sheets("Planners").Range("A3").CopyFromRecordset rsTest
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: wow that worked flawlessly, I thought it was more difficult than that.
thanks man.

Comment: you don't need to declare a recordset in this case - in fact this can be done in one line:  Sheets("Planners").Range("A3").CopyFromRecordset DataManager.GetData